# Getting Python script output in PHP variable

Tags: python, php

I have python script which perfom google search and print a links to the results

```
import sys
query = str(sys.argv[1])
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

for j in search(name, tld='com', num=10, stop=10, pause=15):
print(j)
```

It works perfectly fine when i run it from the termianl but whe i tried to run it from PHP i didn't get any output

```
<?php
     $query = "test";     
           
    echo "Below result of query <strong>\"$query\"</strong> <br>";
     $command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/search.py $query ");
     $output = shell_exec($command);
     echo $output;      
?>
```

I tried to run below script in the same way and it works fine.

```
 import sys
 num_1 = int(sys.argv[1])
 num_2 = int(sys.argv[2])
 product = num_1 * num_2
 print(f"{num_1} * {num_2} = {product}")
```

Comment: how are you running the script? via website? probably WWW user doesn't have access to python; anyway it's a waste of time, google will start to ask for captcha after like 15 requests

Comment: yes, via website it will not be used much so i hope that it will not be blocked. Or will be anyway?

Comment: I'm guessing that www user doesn't have python executable added to paths. Try `$command = escapeshellcmd("/(full_path_to_the_python3_executable)/python3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/search.py $query ");`

Comment: I get the same result. It's strange becasue 2nd script works fine...

Comment: `$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/search.py $query 2>&1");` <--- run this and see if you get any result, it redirects STDERR to STDOUT, so if the script actually runs, but fails in python, it should return some errors. I guess it fails because `name` is not defined. Or google already asks for captcha and it won't return any results for you this way.

Comment: Still don't have anything in the output